# non trivial solutions of homogeneous system

Tags: matrix

I am trying to calculate the non trivial solution of homogeneous system in the form of Ax=0.

but when I was using the function LinearSolve[m,b], it only gives trivial solutions.

Can someone help me with it? Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried `NullSpace`?

Answer (score 1):

```
NMinimize[{(x.x - 1)^2, A.x == 0}, x] (*A=nxn,x={x1,x2,...xn}*)
```

will solve your problem numerically!

Comment: This will work for 1-dimensional null spaces, but if you want to find vectors that span higher dimensional null spaces you will have to do some additional work. Also, the following syntax will make the code work automatically: `Unevaluated[NMinimize[{(x.x - 1)^2, A.x == 0}, x]] /. {x -> Array[x, Length[A[[1]]]]}`.

Comment: @Sjoerd Smit You're right! The use of Nullspace is preferable, but repeated adapted  NMinimize also works...